# Solaris unix NLWP limit

Tags: java, unix, solaris, java-threads

I have a question regarding increasing the limit of NLWP under one process on unix solaris.

Suppose one java process is running and if I type command like this

```
prstat
```

It gives output with following content:

> java/2000

Here 2000 are NLWP.
So how can I increase or decide this limit of NLWP?

Thanak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, there is no hardcoded limit but there might be settings that cap the number of threads par task, project or zone. See:

```
task.max-lwps, project.max-lwps and zone.max-lwps
```

Otherwise, you might reach limits depending on the stack size and the kind of jvm used.

If you get out of memory errors, switch to a 64 bit JVM if not already and, if compatible with your code, try reducing the size of the java stack size with the `-Xss` option, e.g.

```
-Xss128k
```

but beware too small a stack my lead to java.lang.StackOverflowError errors.

Finally, if your java process is limiting itself to some number of thread, there is nothing you can do with JVM or system tuning. Have a look to the code or the program documentation.

Comment: Yea. We are running on 64 bit JVM. We have following settings. -Xss256k
-XX:+UseLargePages
-XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=256m. And cna you elaborate on task.max-lwps, project.max-lwps and zone.max-lwps? Where can I change/check this.?

Comment: This is out of scope for stackoverflow but have a look to `prctl <pid>` output and  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19044-01/sol.containers/817-1592/rmctrls.task-3/index.html for a starter.

Comment: Thanks. It shows same for all- 2.15G. project.max-lwps
        system          2.15G     max   deny                                 -
Can you tell me please that how this is related to no of threads? Or it is just related to size of stack?

Comment: That just means there is essentially no capping on the number of threads, a.k.a. lwp, for the probed process. More precisely, the capping is set to 2.15 billions of threads (probably 0x90000000) which is large enough for other limits like memory availability to be reached before that one.

Comment: Okay so coming back to question. Out jvm crashes when NLWP is between 2100-2300. So it means max thread limit is 2300. How to increase this?

Comment: It doesn't mean the thread limit is 2300. It means something unexpected happens, likely an out of memory. Please post full `prstat` details just before the crash instead of just the number of threads. GC logs would help too.

Comment: This are three outputs of prstat just before 5 minutes.                        (it runs at each 5 minutes )                                                                     5709 ABC_prd  3242M 2416M sleep   59    0   3:30:15 7.2% java/2066

5709 ABC_prd  3242M 2416M sleep   59    0   3:31:07 7.8% java/2065
 
5709 ABC_prd  3242M 2416M sleep   59    0   3:31:53 9.4% java/2066

Comment: Double check if the JVM is really 64bit, e.g. `file /proc/5709/object/a.out`

Comment: Okay but dont you think that this3242M and 2416 dependent on heap size? Which is given xms 1536 and xmx 2048

Comment: do you need some more info??

Comment: At least the last one I asked for. You might also want to edit your question and add all the details scattered in these comments.

Comment: You are right.. **a.out:          ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped, no debugging information available**.. Now how to make this 64 bit then? I will update the question accordingly. Thanks

Comment: You make your application running a 64 bit jvm by adding the `-d64` flag to its `java` command line.

Comment: thanks. It was there. But I was making a mistake with D64(block).  Now the limit was crossed till 3000+ but I have got slower processing of orders.